# Change default application for a File type

Tags: wine, files, microsoft-office

I have installed MS Office 2007 via wine, which all works remarkably well.

However, MS Office has now laid claim to any 'office' files on my computer.

Is there a way to change the default application for a file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just right click the file, properties > Open with, and move the mark to the program you wish to be default?

Comment: On Oneiric the Proprierties doesn't allow to set a custom app to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I followed:

Right-click on a file icon → Properties → Open With → Set as Default → Close.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu-Tweak has a file type manager however to install it you will have to google for it and if you want to use it in natty you will need a ppa.