# How do I set a wine program (ex. Foxit Reader for Windows) as the default program?

Tags: wine, pdf, default-programs

I regularly annotate pdf files and unfortunately there is no *good* linux pdf reader that supports *decent* annotations. Evince has a very rudimentary and buggy annotation feature. So I'm stuck using a Windows viewer through wine.

This works pretty well but, when I simply right-click a file (in this case a pdf), properties, open with and selected Foxit Reader, the Unity Launcher icon remained the wine icon instead of the application icon.

Has anyone set a wine program as the default program for any file?

Any ideas?

Comment: Foxit Reader has Ubuntu package. You don't need to run it under Wine, unless you want to

Comment: Found this page which explains how to do this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine but I'm stuck at the last step: 11.10 doesn't permit me to set a custom command as the default application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Here's how:

**Step 1: Create script**

I followed the procedure in the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine page:

gedit ~/.wine/Foxit5

Now paste the following script in it, save and close gedit. If you changed the installation path, modify the 2nd line accordingly.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

QUICKPARLOCATION="c:\\Program Files\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\\Foxit Reader.exe"
PARAM=`winepath -w "$*"`
wine "$QUICKPARLOCATION" "$PARAM"
exit 0
```

---

Make sure the file is executable with this command.

```
chmod +x ~/.wine/Foxit5
```

**Step 2: Create .desktop file**

Info from this site: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863021

1. cd to the directory /usr/share/applications
2. use 'grep -i foxit *' this will search for the name foxit ignoring case.
3. if it's not there make one from one of the smaller ones.
4. I used sol.destop and copied it to my own fake app.
5. Don't forget the %f, this shows that the application can be passed a file name, it has to be there to show up in the list.

   sudo cp sol.desktop foxit.destop

   gksudo gedit foxit.desktop

foxit.desktop Code: (I created an icon and saved it in the .icons folder)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Foxit Reader 5
Comment=Read and annotate pdf files
Exec=~/.wine/Foxit5 %f
Icon=~/.icons/Foxit.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Office;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=Foxit
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=foxit reader
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=Zwischenlager
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
StartupNotify=true
X-HildonDesk-ShowInToolbar=true
X-Osso-Service=org.gnome.Games.AisleRiot
X-Osso-Type=application/x-executable
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=aisleriot
```

**Step 3: Set as default**

Open file manager and find any pdf file.
Click properties.
Open with.
Show all.
Choose Foxit Reader

That's it! Well sort of… This method works only if Foxit reader 4 is not running. If it is a "file not found" error pops up.

**EDIT: This methods works fully with Foxit Reader 5 but you would need to install wine 1.5 for this version to work. Visit http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu to do so.**

Answer (score 3):

I would do what zetah says:

go to:

> http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/

In the drop down select:

> Desktop Linux

In the pop-up dialog box select package type:

> deb

Then you can install the .deb file

> sudo dpkg -i FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb

Being honest though I have found the built-in PDF reader to meet all my expectations and have not needed Foxit on the Ubuntu side of things. I do use Foxit on my Windows VM though.

If you need advanced features like Annotations and Hilighting you can use:

[Okular][3] or even Inkscape

Comment: A caveat is that the Linux version may not be as "up to date" as the Windows version: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/download.html indicates 08/13/09.

Comment: The Linux version doesn't support annotations. That's the reason I use the Windows version.

Comment: Inkscape is not capable of annotations. You may import **one page** from a pdf to convert it to an svg file.

Comment: Okular doesn't save annotations in the pdf file. They are stored in the configuration folder. So annotating a file and sharing with someone else is not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look in 2 related answers on how setting default applications: [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/67253/28076) and [this another one](https://askubuntu.com/a/26808/28076).

Note that it should not be necessary to run Foxit Reader via Wine, as there is a Ubuntu package for it already.

Comment: Those methods work well with non-wine programs only it seems.

Comment: @ToDo Your answer is very comprehensive... mark it as the right one. Looking at it, I think it'd be better to provide the real example on your script for `QUICKPARLOCATION` on step 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Foxit Reader version for Linux: https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/

It's a .tar.gz file and they give instructions for installation.

Comment: by now the foxit linux version is completely outdated and not developed anymore