# a good PDF viewer for ubuntu that supports text highlighting?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)

I am new in ubuntu and I need a pdf viewer software that support text highlighting and comments,guide me please,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no native linux pdf viewer which offers decent annotation features.

I resolved to using Foxit Reader **for Windows** (the Linux version is really basic). and PDF Xchange Viewer through Wine (1.5 version installed through a [ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu)). The former works better under wine but the latter has in-built OCR and better annotation facilities in my opinion. It is a close match in any case. I've been using Foxit Reader 5.4 till last week and I'm using XChange viewer now.

To make it work in the best of ways, here's how: https://askubuntu.com/a/95404/27968

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5875879/the-best-pdf-viewer-for-linux

Comment: Since this answer was posted, Okular has added the ability to annotate PDFs.  See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs).